# How to get the return value of a JavaScript function/Object on Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

How can i can get/capture the value of a JavaScript object on the page rendered in a webbrowser control, or alternatively capture the return value of a function?

The only example I saw is the following in delphi. Looking for a better solution in C#

http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the InvokeScript call of HtmlDocument. [MSDN documentation on ObjectForScripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One piece of info missing is what you want to capture it to. I personally use Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It allows you to use the Javascript command `console.log(object);` to log an object to the Firebug console. Same applies for function return values, `console.log(myFunc());`.